# Ramsey model problem

Tags: macroeconomics, microeconomics, mathematical-economics, economic-growth, ramsey

1. Explain the no-Ponzi game condition throughout the function.
2. Does the constrain function:[image]  also reflect include the No-Ponzi condition?

Answer (score 1):

The no-Ponzi condition is a technical condition that needs to be imposed to deal with the case of a time-varying value like capital `k` diverging at infinity. Even if penalised by an exponential discount, if `k` increases too fast, its integral will have a non-zero value/undefined value in the limit.

In this particular case, I cannot be sure what it is being asked of you. Technically, the budget constraint you wrote implies something about the behaviour of the functions `w(t)` and `c(t)` at infinity. (You cannot write the integral if they diverge faster than the exponential discounting can handle!) But, most likely, the answer that you need is that there is no no-Ponzi condition in there, and it needs to be factored in later.
Look in the paper/textbook for its correct statement.

Also, your definition of `R(t)` is wrong.